# The issues of exporting/importing certificate , private key under keychain access for Iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to export the certificate and private key from one machine to another so I can reuse the provisioning profile.

There's a private key under the certificate in keychain access.

1)I exported the the certificate as certifcate .cer  file then I imported that from another machine. However , it's missiong the private key. and xcode on the new machine complaining no valid signing key available for the imported provisioning profile.

2) Next I try to export the certificate and the private key as personal information exhange .p12 format, this time it prompted me to input a password which I did.

3)I imported the .p12 file into the new machine, this time the new machine complaining error, cannot read the contents.

So, what should I do to properly export both the certificate and private key and import them into the new machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope it may help you
In Keychain, select three items: Your private key, public key and the cert from Apple

CMD+Click to select "export 3 items"

and you will export one .cer file. Then double click to import the file without keying any password to protect so.

or you should import cert first and then import both public and private key.
Make sure you also have the Apple Developer Relations Root CA certificate in your keychain. That is what is used to verify the certificate. See in your keychain access whether it has been paired correctly.

Comment: do you mean to export 4 items,  developer certificate, public key, private key, and apple root CA certificate? Do CMD-SHIFT and export all 4 as one single file with extension .cer?   or can you export as 4 individual .cer files?  But it wouldn't make sense to name a key as .cer certificate extension.

Comment: Yes. you must have Apple Developer Relations Root CA certificate in your keychain.

Comment: OK, I moved them all into login keycahin area and able to select them all, and exported them as one single certificate file.

Comment: @Praveen for me i only see two things the cert and the private key, I exported them as you suggested, it exported as .p12 file. After that i followed the steps and it works like a charm thanks a lot

Comment: @Praveen-K doesn't seem as though the public key is actually necessary, just the private key.

Answer (score 3):

With Xcode 5.0+, this has become very simple. 
1. On the computer with the developer credentials, 
   Goto Xcode->Preferences->Accounts.
   Click on the gears to export the profile. Choose a password as it includes all your credentials of apple-developer program. 
2. Share the exported file with the new computer. 
3. Import the profile in your Xcode->preferences->Accounts.

Comment: with Xcode 5, it just errors out saying ' could not export identity from the keychain'  any ideas ?