# Apple Developer certificate on multiple computers, one individual developer account

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

Can I have 2 separate provisioning profiles for an individual Apple Dev account.

Basically I need to develop using 2 different laptops. I am not able to generate a new certificate without revoking the already existing one from my first laptop+email. Can I have a way around this?

Comment: Oh God the woes of Apple Developer Certificates... Good Luck. I am quite sure I got it working on two machines, but it is no fun. You must move your private Keys on both machines. Move as in export them,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006845/the-issues-of-exporting-importing-certificate-private-key-under-keychain-acces I didn't read all the way, but it looked like the correct steps.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll have to try it later, don't have one of the laptop at hand. And I agree with you, Apple sure made it overly complicated.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so, but you need the private key and the certificate together on both the machines. else it will not work. There will be a "No valid identity found" error.